# Comparing output for n frame in opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to compare number which repeat minimum 8 times in output ie

suppose my output = 3 is same for next 8 frames then i need a output as 3,

> output = 3
>   output = 3
>   output = 3
>   output = 3
>   output = 3
>   output = 3
>   output = 3

i used opencv and c++ language, any help

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quiet clear. I guess what you want is something like this:

```
int triggerVal;
int triggerCount = 0;
for()
{
    //output obtained.
    if(triggerVal != output)
    {
        triggerVal = output;
        triggerCount = 1;
    }
    else
        triggerCount++;

    if(triggerCount>8)
        printf("%d\n",triggerVal);
}
```